# How do I create a primary key whose value is an existing column concatenated with another column?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I am aware that you can have a composite key in sql, however that is not what I am looking to do. My reasoning is because the table already exists with data in it and I am looking for a sort of quick fix that doesn't involve creating a new table and essentially deprecating the old one. When I tried to make existing columns into a composite key I get an error message that says making these changes will require the table to be dropped and recreated. So, what I want to do is add a primary key column that is an nvarchar that is created from an existing column that is an nvarchar concatenated with another existing column that is a bigint. Is this possible and if so how can I do this as a query or from the design screen for the table in sql server management studio?

Comment: Did you try a computed column?

Comment: You can actually switch that off in SSMS. Go to Tools\Options\Designers and uncheck the option for "Prevent saving changes that require table recreation".

You can then make your changes and under the covers a new table will be created, the data copied over and the original one dropped.

Comment: @MartinCairney but the better alternative is to learn to write these changes yourself and avoid using the visual designer to change table structure.

Comment: I agree but I don't have very much experience with sql.

Comment: @DavidCarek Then your question should be a request for someone to guide you in writing an alter statement to create a primary key constraint. If you post the table and column names (preferably as DDL), I sure someone can provide the statement to do that. And now would be a good time to verify that you have a current, good backup of your database BEFORE something goes wrong accidentally.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree that understanding what is required, or is happening under the covers is important. Maybe worth also adding that if you then also script the change rather than just executing it directly then you see the T-SQL and can then use that to increase your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a database backup.

Then, if you just want to change your primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    columnA ASC,
    columnB ASC
)
```

If you really want to create a new column, which is the primary key and whose value is an existing column concatenated with another column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD NewColumn AS (nvarcharColumn + cast(bigIntColumn as nvarchar(50))) PERSISTED  NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].MyTable ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    NewColumn ASC
)
```